# Check if request to a URL is from our server or it's an external request

Tags: python, http-post, tornado

Using python tornado, I want to check if a request to a URL is from our server or it's an external request. what is the purpose? I have some internal URLs which used by my ajax requests. if a user can access my URLs and send request to them, it can ruins my statistic calculations.
How to check if a request to a specific URL is internal or external? or even from specific IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Tornado's documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch2.2/httpserver.html#tornado.httpserver.HTTPRequest) you should access field `remote_ip` of `tornado.httpserver.HTTPRequest`, that contains client's IP-address. Having a list of internal IPs you can distinct internal vs external IPs.